# Code Isn't Displaying All of The Data

Tags: javascript, ajax

My project allows the user to select their **State**, **County**, and **City**. Once the user selects **State**, it generates the **Counties** that the user can select. This also happens for **City**. Currently, the list of **cities** doesn't display all of the **cities**. What is my `loadCities` method doing wrong?

> Issue: my `loadCities` function is not displaying all of the cities available.

**My loadCounties function is working as expected:**

```
function loadStates(){
    // This is working correctly
}
```

**My loadCounties function is also working correctly:**

```
function loadCounties(stateId){
    // This is working correctly
}
```

**The error is occuring in my loadCities function:**

```
function loadCities(countyId, stateCode, countryCode) {
    var cityUrl, cityData;

    cityUrl = WorkLocation.ListOfCityJsonUrls;
    cityData = { countyId: countyId };

    $.ajax({
        url: cityUrl,
        data: cityData,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(result) {
            var key = "dataForCity_" + currentWorkArea("countyselected").data("id");

            setWorkAreaData(key, data);
            bindCityData();
            syncSelections(countyId, 3);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: does this help, `cityData = { "countyId": countyId };`?

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary, unfortunately this doesn't change the output.

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary That wouldn't change anything. You only need to quote keys if they have invalid characters such as "-", "&", or "%".

Comment: Can you check if you are getting some sort of error during the ajax call?? If not then try pass a callback function to handle the success scenario.

Comment: @CodeChaser You really do not have enough information out here, with which to track your problem. Are you saying you get some of the cities, but not all?

Comment: @lfedi Okonkwo sorry about the lack of code. This is the only section I see that could be affecting the city output... You are correct, I am getting some cities, but not all of them.

Comment: Right after the ajax call, if you `console.log(result);`, it should give you the raw return from the server. If all your expected data is in there, then stay on the front end looking for the issue. If not, then go back to the data source (e.g. database query) and check it out. Of course, I'm assuming that `cityData` contains the correct value you wish to send in!

Comment: hmmm. I put the `console.log(result);` right after my closing ajax call `});` but it is returning a `Uncaught ReferenceError` am I inserting this into the correct place?